# Черный статус бар в iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c

После открытия меню в приложении, статус бар iPhone (там где часы, название мобильного оператора и индикатор батареи) становится полностью черным.
Проблема возникает исключительно в iOS11, в iOS10 не появляется.

У кого-нибудь подобное было?

Код, к сожалению, не могу показать.

Comment: Покажите Debug view hierarchy

Comment: А Вы случайно status bar скрывать не пытаетесь (например, вместе с navigation bar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым.
Надо было принудительно установить backgroundColor для UIView, которая накладывалась на основной экран на время показа меню.

То что у нее уже ранее был задан backgroundColor, при изменениях игнорировалось.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте написать вручную `statusBar = .light`.

Точно не помню, но суть такая.

Comment: Уже пробовал. Менял и в настройках проекта, и устанавливал в AppDelegate и в конкретном UIViewController.